# Applying functions to lists with substitution

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I was trying to make a function that quickly calculates fractions. In my particular case there a factorials, so it s kinda easy. I wrote a `make_coprime` function which makes two numbers coprime (and returns a pair, which bothers me a little: it sounds a bit too complicated, is there no way to make it return 2 numbers? Looks like there isn't, but just to be sure)

Now it is something like frac{numbers]/{numbers} and I want to make all of the upper ones coprime with all the lower ones.

So I have two lists and I want to apply my function to all possible pairs with substitution after that. This is where I failed. I couldn't even do it with one element and a list, my best was

```
f a [] = (a, [1])
f a x:xs = ((fst (make_coprime a x)), ((snd (make_coprime a x)):(snd (f (fst (make_coprime a x)) xs))))
```

(there is a parse error somewhere here, but I can't find it at all)

But I feel like I overcomplicate things. It sounds way simplier than it looks when I write it. Is there an elegant way to do this?

Comment: What difference do you think there would be between returning a pair and returning two numbers?

Comment: No, seems like no difference at all. Though maybe in this particualr case there is a way to build it in somehow. 
I just didn't like using (fst (make_coprime a b)) to extract data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parsing error is that you've not used parens around `x:xs`.

Before saying any more: Haskell functions should always come with a type signature, which makes it hugely easier to reason what we're talking about and where any. I'm not sure what you want, but likely

```
makeCoprime :: Integer -> Integer -> (Integer,Integer)
```

and

```
f :: Integer -> [Integer] -> (Integer, [Integer])
```

Apart from that (and to find other parse errors, which occur before the type system ever takes action), I'd first try to write it as readable as possible. First align everything meaningfully:

```
f a (x:xs) = ( (fst (make_coprime a x))
             , ( (snd (make_coprime a x))
                 : (snd (f (fst (make_coprime a x)) xs))
               )
             )
```

ok, now there are a couple of parens that are *not* necessary and should be omitted: the `,` always seperates everything, so you never need to write e.g. `(1, (2))`: just make it `(1,2)`. And function application binds more *tightly* than any infix operator, so you also never need to write `(f x) : y`, just do `f x : y`. That makes your code

```
f a (x:xs) = ( fst (make_coprime a x)
             , snd (make_coprime a x)
                 : snd (f (fst (make_coprime a x)) xs)
             )
```

which is already a good deal easier to understand. You could get rid of more parens by using the [`$`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-Function.html#v:-36-) and [`.`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-46-) operators, but I'll leave that.

What I would definitely not leave, as chepner suggests, are these multiple invokations of `make_coprime a x`. This kind of duplication is not only code-noise, it can also make your program run very slow.

```
f a (x:xs) = ( fst axCoprimes
             , snd axCoprimes
                 : snd (f (fst axCoprimes) xs)
             )
 where axCoprimes = make_coprime a x
```

Now, all you ever do with `axCoprimes` is eval the `fst` and `snd` components separately. Thus instead of giving the tuple *one* name, you should immediately match the components:

```
f a (x:xs) = (p₀, p₁ : snd (f p₀ xs))
 where (p₀,p₁) = make_coprime a x
```

and there you go, that looks very clear IMO.

Comment: Wow, i just forgot to insert it lol. My type signatures were `make_coprime :: (Integral a) => a -> a -> (a, a)` and `f :: (Integral a) => a -> [a] -> (a, [a])` which is kinda same, right?

Comment: Yeah, it's just more general (also works with `Int` instead of `Integer`).

Answer (score 4):

You only need to call `coprime a x` once; you can assign its return value to a name using a `let` statement:

```
f a (x:xs) = let pair = make_coprime a x 
             in  ((fst pair), ((snd pair):(snd (f (fst pair) xs))))
```

(Your parse error is likely due to the missing parentheses around `x:xs`.)

You can simplify it more by unpacking the pair immediately instead of calling `fst` and `snd` repeatedly.

```
f a (x:xs) = let (n1,n2) = make_coprime a x 
             in  (n1, (n2:(snd (f n1 xs))))
```

Comment: I'm going then to apply this to a whole list of arguments instead of just one. Which will make it longer. Is there a way to make this to list thing at once? 

(by the way my function does not work still. It compiles but then it just `Non type-variable in the constraint Num (t -> t1)`

Comment: @user8568658 add type signatures! that will make your error messages clearer!